# Program don't respond when using a long for loop

Tags: c#, loops, long-integer

I have a loop for a button click that checks if a site is available or not and it gets site list into an array and check them one by one with a for loop and if they where available it adds a text to a textbox but when my list gets long program not responds and after about 10seconds all results will written in that textbox together not one by one, even if list was not long and it was proccessing well, I can't to anything with program like moving it, is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: Yes but that question can't be "answered" - Do some research into threads and/or background worker

Comment: You are blocking your UI thread. Good time to learn **Tasks**...

Comment: This is where you also get to learn about Threading as well. You'll need two threads - one to do the logic, the other to update the UI..

Comment: @user1666620, no, he doesn't need two threads. He already has one GUI thread that should update UI. Therefore, he needs only one additional thread to check sites.

Comment: @cassandradied you just agreed with me - he needs two threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your CPU heavy loop is done on the GUI thread which means that it can't update the screen anymore which causes Windows to think it stopped responding while actually it's just doing a bunch of work and doesn't have time to update it's screen.

Use a `BackgroundWorker` to accomplish this by running the loop in another thread : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx.
Move your loop code to the `DoWork` of the `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be using async/await

```
async private void button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var url in sites)
    {
        bool available = await Task.Run(() =>
          {
              //Do your work here
              return true; //or false; 
          });

        //Update UI here
    }
}
```

For more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: you need to use progress updates to update UI, above code just makes UI responsive, it does not updates UI periodically. [See progress updates here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx)

Comment: @Downvoter, which part is wrong?

Comment: Why can I see downvote? Anyways nothing is wrong. Might be someone downvoted after seeing my comment. I commented to make the answer more helpful, Not to say its wrong or should be downvoted.